# Count by ratio and then group by MSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
ID Name

1 ABC
1 DEF
1 VVV
1 BBB
1 BCD
2 ZZZ
2 BAA
3 AAA
3 BBB
3 BBC
```

I want to get the ratio of all the names that start with A to All the names that start with B group by ID.

So the output should be

```
ID Ratio

1  0.5
2  0
3  0.33
```

.

```
SELECT (ID, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'A%') /
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'B%')) AS `ratio` from table Group by ID
```

does not give me the right answer. It takes the total ratio of A/B across all ID's into account and writes that number for all the ID's.

Comment: I'm sorry. What do u mean by COUNT(DISTINCT ID

Comment: To replace COUNT(*) in your query with COUNT(DISTINCT ID). This should work if you try to get A's and B's of distinct ID

Comment: Same thing............. Doesn't give me right answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    SUM(IF(name LIKE 'A%',1,0))/SUM(IF(name like 'B%',1,0)) 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd try:

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN B = 0 THEN 0 ELSE A/B END AS Ratio FROM
    ( SELECT ID,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B
      FROM my_table GROUP BY ID ) AS grouped;
```

The inner SELECT gets the group IDs, and for every ID, the number of items beginning with A and those beginning with B.

The outer SELECT (you can omit it if you're sure that there'll always be at least one B-row) checks that the ratio makes sense before attempting to calculate it.

Or else:

```
SELECT ID, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        /  SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)
FROM my_table GROUP BY ID;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that, if the number of B-rows is zero, the division will yield NULL. The COALESCE transforms that NULL in a 0.